# Worlds easiest Postgresql ... not working?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have read every stack question on how to do the worlds simplest update statement in postgresql and i still manage to get this update wrong?

```
update roles set role="Blog-Owner" where role="Blow-Owner";
```

Apparently:

```
ERROR:  column "Blog-Owner" does not exist
LINE 1: update roles set role="Blog-Owner" where role="Blow-Owner";
```

Duh, I am trying to set the value of Blog-Owner where the current value is Blow-Owner...

Any one got any ideas >..>

Comment: Please read the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 5):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes.

```
update roles set role='Blog-Owner' where role='Blow-Owner';
```

Comment: Seriously? oO - I didnt think that was a thing

Comment: In PostgreSQL, double quotes enclose column names, system identifiers, etc. You can read about it [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Things_to_find_out_about_when_moving_from_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL)

Comment: Yeah, it's a thing and it can be confusing, especially when using multiple types of DBMS. Personally, I try to keep 2 things in mind: 1) string literals should be in single quotes, and 2) name your schema's, tables and columns so that you don't need any funky characters (e.g. backticks, square brackets) to be able to use them.

Comment: @MarianoD'Ascanio: I think you mean to say *In SQL, ...*. I'm pretty sure the use of single and double quotes is actually in The Standard. Databases that use backticks (MySQL) or brackets (SQL Server) for quoting identifiers are non-standard.

Comment: @MarianoD'Ascanio Actually, PostgreSQL follows the ANSI standard - `"identifier"` and `'literal'`. Unfortunately not many others do - though MySQL can (and should) be set to ANSI mode, and MS-SQL understands ANSI quoting even if it still defaults to its insane `[identifier]` quotes.

Comment: @muistooshort and Craig Ringer, you are both right, it is in _ANSI SQL_, which is followed by _PostgreSQL_.